# When starting the node project, it seems like babel-core has made a mistake

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

```
OS: Win10
Node: v7.10
NPM: v4.2.0
Node-gyp: v3.6.2
```

`npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @souche-f2e/sad@1.10.5 requires a peer of antd@2.8.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN sad@2.0.0 No repository field.`

I can execute `npm run i` successfully(But some warns),and when i want to execute `npm run start`, i encountered a mistake that :

`Module build failed: Error: Plugin 0 specified in "base" provided an invalid property of "default"
at Plugin.init
(D:\xx\xxx\web\src\main\antd\node_modules\babelcore\lib\transformation\plugin.js:131:13)`

There is another one I care about is

`npm WARN @souche-f2e/sad@1.10.5 requires a peer of antd@2.8.0 but none was installed.`

What may be the reason?

Comment: is `npm run i` working properly.

Comment: what is your webpack configuration??

Comment: @pritesh i haven't install webpack,if everything is right, i only need to install node-gyp and `npm run i` + `npm run start`, this project will be ok

Comment: @pritesh i think `npm run i` is working properly ,it is only three warns